# Flex Spark List with SQL Result

Tags: list, sqlite, apache-flex, flex-spark

I'm trying to populate a spark list component from SQLite in an AIR application

```
statusList = new ArrayCollection(statement.getResult().data);
myList.dataprovider = statusList;
```

From the debug session I know the data is structured as statusList->unnamed object->array

```
<s:List width="100%" height="100%" id="listUploadStatus" dataProvider="{statusList}">
    <s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:Label text="{HOW DO I ACCESS INDIVIDUAL FIELD HERE?}" width="125"/>      
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

**UPDATE**
The fields are:

1) NAME
2) IMAGE_URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<s:List width="100%" height="100%" id="listUploadStatus" dataProvider="{statusList}">
    <s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <s:ItemRenderer>
                <s:Label text="{data.myAwesomeField}" width="125"/>      
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Comment: I tried data.IMAGE_URL but I got this error ==> warning: unable to bind to property 'image_url' on class 'Object' (class is not an IEventDispatcher). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First of all, it's not an error, it's a warning. It simply means that if any changes are made to your object, your itemRenderer won't be able to detect them. Search for "data binding flex itemrenderer" in Google...